# player input not invoking functions defined for actions

Tags: unity-game-engine

i am using a player input component in my player to take input, player input behaviour is set to send messages, So i have made the "OnAction" functions for all the actions in the player script attached to player.

the problem is the functions are not getting invoked at all and before i was using unity events in the player input behaviour and they were also not getting triggered. i checked input debugger inputs are registering. I have tried restarting the computer and the editor and i have added control schemes, but nothing changed. Please help!

[project screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pLZTT.png)

Comment: Without seeing your code and having more details about your settings (which input system do you use, etc.) it's almost impossible to guess what's going wrong in your project...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.